# How can you dynamically create a ui-sref argument?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My page contains a "next" link which may point to a page or may point to an article:

```
<a ui-sref="page({slug: nextPage.slug}">Next</a>
```

or

```
<a ui-sref="article({slug: nextArticle.slug}">Next</a>
```

I can generalise the slug by turning it into a variable but I'm finding it hard to generalise the function that's being called and alter it from `article` to `page`:

```
<a ui-sref="__method__({slug: linkSlug}">Next</a>
```

How can pass in the method that should be called?

...Or alternatively, if I knew what it's callee was I could pass it as an array method (since `window'alert' will do exactly that). What object is it being called on? If I knew that I could use:

```
<a ui-sref="callee[methodName]({slug: linkSlug})">Next</a>
```

**NB** I have tried using `this[methodName]({slug: linkSlug})` and it doesn't work and produces the error: `Error: Could not resolve 'this['page']' from state 'page'`

Answer (score 0):

So the answer turns out to be that you can pass the `ui-sref` argument as a string.

```
## in your controller
$scope.srefMethodAndArgs = 'page({slug: nextPage.slug})'

## in your view
<a ui-sref="{{ srefMethodAndArgs }}" ng-if="srefMethodAndArgs">Next</a>
```

However there are a couple of things to watch about this

1. You need to put this string inside the angular evaluation brackets: `{{ }}`
2. `ui-sref` will throw an error if the method and args aren't valid. So if they're being dynamically loaded into the page then adding the `ng-if` statement ensures that they don't cause problems when they're not present.